# Managing the Xen Cloud Platform

Tags: xen

Could someone recommend a web-based tool for managing XCP? I have 6-7 x64 boxes that I would build into a small private cloud for a group of developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL for CloudStack: http://cloudstack.org/

Zentific (http://www.zentific.com/software.html) is planning to have XCP support for its upcoming release at the end of the month.

Also, depending on the use case Xen VNC Proxy (XVP) could be useful (http://www.xvpsource.org/).

Also we keep track of all of the XCP project on the wiki:
http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/XCP_Projects

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.xencloudcontrol.com/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/xenwebmanager/
Also, take a look at cloud stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cloudmin:

http://www.webmin.com/cloudmin.html

Is there a GPL and commercial version.